# How to make this jquery Masonry center?

Tags: css

I have a sample website from [this](http://www.responsivewebmobile.com/app/webroot/rwm_pin_page/).
But i don't know how to make it "center"?

There is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Responsive Web Mobile - Basic Pin Page Responsive</title>

   <!-- Included Bootstrap CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />

    <!-- Includes FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- Website CSS Theme Css -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stylesheet.css" />

</head>
<body>  

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="main" class="container">
            <div id="items" class="row-fluid" >
                <div class="item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_04.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_07.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author"> - John White - </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_01.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_02.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_03.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_05.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" item masonry-brick">
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a class="image" title="Title" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="./img/image_08.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="description">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    11 May 2013
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                    <a href="#">John</a>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i>
                                    10
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer id="footer"></footer>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And css file

```
    body {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.wrapper {}

#main {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

#items {}

#items .item {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F6F6F6 0%, #EAEAEA 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #DDDDDD;
    width: 236px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#items .item .item-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

#items .item .picture .description {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#items .item .meta span {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 16px !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#items .item .picture {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

#items .item .picture a.image {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#items .item .picture img {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.picture img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}


.navbar-inner {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #999 !important;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS HACKS
 -------------------------------------------------- */
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
  #main {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: No answer found using a search engine? This seems a good candidate for a FAQ.

Comment: Hi, i am still looking for answer.

Comment: I found a soluation is add class="container" to "main" div, but now only shown 4 columns in center.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I may help you with it if you provide me some codes, like how your init your `masory` and the CSS for `.item` (I see it a fixed width but still prefer some code here, kinda lazzy to dig through the whole site to find what I need)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to gather the details I need. Can't test it through debug of devtools because Masory need to reload to re-init the size of `item`. This may work

- Use the class `.container` wrapper. So it will be cantered.
- Init your mansory like this .Don't set the `columnsWidth` property, and use `gutter` instead of margin in your CSS. This is to make your items have dynamic width with CSS

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('#items');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.item',
                isAnimated: true,
                gutter: 10
            });
        });
    });
```

- In your CSS .Set `width` to dynamic, dont use `float` or `margin` (Because you use gutter instead of margin ^**above**)

```css
#items .item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F6F6F6 0%, #EAEAEA 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #DDDDDD;
    width: 20%;
}
```

- When it come to small screen size, use `@media` query

```css
@media (max-width: 768px){
  #items item{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```